# Is there any way to emit an event in Solidity that does not log?

Tags: events, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am interested in writing a simple application that emits events for notifications when a certain piece of data in the smart contract changes. These events do not need to persist, they can be fleeting and if a user misses one, it is not important, so they do not need to be logged.

Here is a sample smart contract with a basic event that is emitted in the `setText` function. What would I change to make the event NOT logged, and therefore not taking up disk space somewhere?

```js
contract HelloWorld {
    string public text = "Hello World";

    event NewText(
        string _text
    );

    constructor() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    function setText(string memory _text) public {
        text = _text;
        emit NewText(_text);
    }
}
```

Or is there some better way to achieve what I'm going for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

events do not take up space in your contract. That is why it is cheaper than using a state variable.

Hashes of events are stored in the `logsBloom` which is stored in the header of each block.

logs itself stored in the `transaction receipt` which are stored in a trie and head of this trie is also stored inside the block header.

You can read this article: [data-transaction-receipt-trie-and-logs-simplified](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-data-transaction-receipt-trie-and-logs-simplified-30e3ae8dc3cf)

> Logs are used to store information that is not required by the
> contract
>
> When the smart contract wants to log data for the aforementioned
> scenarios, it can emit an event which is then written to the
> transaction receipt’s log records. Each transaction has only one
> transaction receipt. In addition to log records, the receipt includes
> status, gas used, and logs bloom

with 100% certainty, I would say no. In Ethereum everything is recorded

Comment: I understand that they do not take up space in the blockchain, but they are still stored somewhere. I'm just curious to know if there's a way to fire an event that is emitted by nodes and forward-able to a frontend, without being persistent or stored anywhere at all.

Comment: with 100% certainty, I would say no. In etherum everything is recorded

Comment: Thank you! If you can edit your answer to say this I can select it as the solution.